# Access the column names in the `mutate_at` to use it for subseting a list

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I am trying to recode several variables but with different recode schemes. 
The recoding scheme is saved in a list where each element is a named vector of the form `old = new`.
Each element is the recoding scheme for each variable in the data frame

I am using the `mutate_at` function and the `recode`.

I think that the problem is that I cannot extract the variable name to use it to get the correct recoding scheme from the list

I tried `deparse(substitute(.))` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321150/update-cell-values-with-the-column-name-using-mutate-at)
and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976669/how-to-use-the-name-of-the-column-im-currently-using-in-a-mutate-at) didn;t help

Also I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868208/extract-column-name-in-mutate-if-call) that I can extract the column name of the variable that is passed with tidyevalution but I again failed to implement it. (also it is using the deprecated 'funs`)

Last, I am hoping that this is the correct approach to recode the variables (i.e. using this recode list inside the mutate). If there is totally different way to approach this multiple recoding please let me know

```
library(dplyr)
# dplyr version 0.8.5

df <- 
  tibble(
    var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "C"),
    var2 = c("X", "Y", "Z", "Z")
  )

recode_list <- 
  list(

    var1 = c(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3),
    var2 = c(X = 0, Y = -1, Z = 1)
  )

recode_list
#> $var1
#> A B C 
#> 1 2 3 
#> 
#> $var2
#>  X  Y  Z 
#>  0 -1  1
```

I am using the `dplyr::recode` function.

```
# recoding works fine when doing it one variable as a time
df %>% 
  mutate(
    var1 = recode(var1, !!!recode_list[["var1"]]),
    var2 = recode(var2, !!!recode_list[["var2"]])
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>    var1  var2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0
#> 2     1    -1
#> 3     2     1
#> 4     3     1
```

When I try to apply a function to do this for all variables, it seems to fail

```
# this does not work.
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), ~{

    var_name <- rlang::quo_name(quo(.))

    recode(., !!!recode_list[[var_name]])
  }
  )
#> Error in expr_interp(f): object 'var_name' not found
```

I also tried `rlang::as_name` and `rlang::as_label` but I think I cannot really capture the name of the variable as a string to use it to subset the `recode_list`.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), ~ {
    var_name <- rlang::as_name(quo(.))
    print(var_name)
    #recode(., !!!recode_list[["var2"]])
  }
  )
#> [1] "."
#> [1] "."
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   var1  var2 
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 .     .    
#> 2 .     .    
#> 3 .     .    
#> 4 .     .


Created on 2020-04-30 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(var1,var2),
            .funs = function(x){recode_list %<>% .[[as_label(enquo(x))]]
            recode(x,!!!recode_list)})
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#   var1  var2
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     0
#2     1    -1
#3     2     1
#4     3     1
```

I suspect this works while placing the subset `recode_list` directly into `recode` does not is because `enquo` delays evaluation of `x` until assignment with `%<>%`. Then `!!!` can force evaluation after it has been properly evaluated previously.

**Edit**

Your approach with `rlang` also works with some modifications:

```
library(rlang)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(var1, var2), function(x) {
    var_name <- rlang::as_label(substitute(x))
    recode(x, !!!recode_list[[var_name]])
  })
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian ! It works! much appreciated!
 (I still don't understand why we should use `enquo` (or `substitute` in base R) instead of `quo`. Also why the `function(x)` works while the `~` does not)

Comment: Also, `quo_name` is deprecated and you can replace it with `as_name`or `as_label`. Thaks again!

Comment: Overall, I think the thing that stopped you was the non-standard evaluation of `.funs = list(~{})`, which I will admit, I don't understand fully. When it doesn't work the way I expect, I just go back to the classic `function(x){}` form.