# Access column names in a function to be used in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, across

Using OECD data, I can retrieve a database where variables are specified by their IDs and a list with the corresponding labels. Here is a minimal example that reproduces the data structure:

```
df <- tibble(LOCATION=c("DEU","ITA","USA"),UNIT=c("DEU","EUR","USD"),value=c(120,140,160))
df
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#> LOCATION UNIT  value
#> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 DEU      DEU     120
#> 2 ITA      EUR     140
#> 3 USA      USD     160

df_labels <- list(LOCATION = data.frame(id =c("DEU","ITA","USA"), 
                                        label=c("Germany","Italy","United States")), 
                  UNIT = data.frame(id=c("USD","EUR"),
                                    label=c("Dollar","Euro")))
df_labels
#> $LOCATION
#>    id         label
#> 1 DEU       Germany
#> 2 ITA         Italy
#> 3 USA United States
#> 
#> $UNIT
#>    id  label
#> 1 USD Dollar
#> 2 EUR   Euro
```

What I want to do is to replace the IDs in variables LOCATION and UNIT in `df` with the corresponding labels provided in `df_labels`.
I defined the following function:

```
get_labels <- function(x,db) {
     variable = deparse(substitute(x))
     return(factor(x,levels=db[[variable]]$id,labels=db[[variable]]$label))
     }
```

so that I can use it in `mutate` as follows:

```
df %>% mutate(LOCATION = get_labels(LOCATION,df_labels),
              UNIT = get_labels(UNIT,df_labels))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   LOCATION      UNIT   value
#>   <fct>         <fct>  <dbl>
#> 1 Germany       Euro     120
#> 2 Italy         Euro     140
#> 3 United States Dollar   160
```

However, I haven't been able to use the function across multiple columns. If I try it using `across`:

```
df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), ~get_labels(.,df_labels)))
```

the result is an `NA` in the affected columns. Apparently, the problem is with `deparse(substitute(.))`, which does not capture the column names. Unfortunately, looking at similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523202/access-the-column-names-in-the-mutate-at-to-use-it-for-subseting-a-list) didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

`across` will not have access to column names so `deparse`, `substitute` trick will not work. Try this version :

```
get_labels <- function(x, y, db) {
  return(factor(x,levels=db[[y]]$id,labels=db[[y]]$label))
}

cols <- sapply(df, is.character)
df[cols] <- purrr::imap_dfc(df[cols], get_labels, db = df_labels)
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  LOCATION      UNIT   value
#  <fct>         <fct>  <dbl>
#1 Germany       NA       120
#2 Italy         Euro     140
#3 United States Dollar   160
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I think I must study how ```purrr``` works, so I can understand what I am doing...

Comment: The only think I don't like much of this solution is that it cannot be used in a pipe (this is why I was trying to use ```mutate```)

Comment: You can do `imap_dfc(dplyr::select(df, where(is.character)), get_labels, db = df_labels)` but it returns only the columns that are changed hence I used `cols`.

Answer (score 1):

We could do this with `deframe` and `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
lst1 <- map(df_labels, deframe)
for(nm in names(lst1))  df <- df %>%
           mutate(!! nm := lst1[[nm]][!! rlang::sym(nm)])
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  LOCATION      UNIT   value
#  <chr>         <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Germany       <NA>     120
#2 Italy         Euro     140
#3 United States Dollar   160
```